# ngFacebook not working with phonegap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

Im using ngFacebook by Almog Baku in my current angular app. In test environment it is working fine. But in apk build via phonegap it isn't working. I have included

`<dependency id="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" />`

and

```
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />
</feature>
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
<param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</feature>
```

into my `config.xml` too but still no InAppBrowser or new tab poping up.

My `App.js` is

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngTouch',
    'ngRoute',
    'myApp.controllers',
    'ngIdle',
    'ngFileUpload',
    'ng.deviceDetector',
    'oitozero.ngSweetAlert',
    'angular-hmac-sha512',
    'ngFacebook'
]);
myApp.config( function( $facebookProvider ) {
    $facebookProvider.setAppId('1869339203095182');
});
```

And in my controller:

```
$scope.login =  function() {
$facebook.login().then(function() {
  refresh();
});
}
$rootScope.$on('event:social-sign-in-success', function(event, userDetails){
 console.log(userDetails);
})
function refresh() {
  $facebook.api("/me",{fields: 'id,name,email'}).then( 
      function(response) 
      {
            //console.log( response );
      },
      function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        //$scope.welcomeMsg = "Please log in";
      }
  ); 
}
refresh();
```

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30380657/cannot-log-into-facebook-via-ngfacebook-on-angularjs-app

Comment: it is working in test environment but not working in apk build. No even poping up any anything.

Comment: @RameshRajendran if you can set bounty for this question please, It will be really big help.

Comment: I'll do it when the bounty is available.

Comment: @RameshRajendran mate pls add some bounty on it now....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For social Media Integration You should use official `cordovaOauth`. You can find all documentation regarding it [here](https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth). But to use it you should include

```
<script src="lib/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

these into your `index.html`. And in your controller call should be:

```
$scope.login =  function() {
$cordovaOauth.facebook("YOUR_APP_ID", ["email","public_profile", "user_friends"]).then(function(result) {
    $http.get("https://graph.facebook.com/me", { params: { access_token: result.access_token, fields: "id,name,email,gender,location,website,picture,relationship_status", format: "json" }}).then(function(result1) {
//this is success call
//console.log(result1)
}, function(error) {
alert("There was a problem getting your profile. Check the logs for details.");
console.log(error);
});
}, function(error) {
console.log(error);
}); 
}
```

Hope this will help you. For more detailed information you can go through `ng-cordova.js` this file.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript on mobile doesn't work good with social medias. It happens mostly because of security restrictions, certificates and so on. Keep in mind with Javascript you can fraud business logic by loading new javascript code after application has been published in AppsStore or Google Play. I believe Facebook blocks javascript implementation on mobile devices.

Some Cordova applications, for example US Bank .., even do not use `$http` or `ajax`because of lack of SSL Pinning, they use native implementation for most of modules.

Don't want to disappoint but ... take a look on this issue: [Does not works on cordova android project](https://github.com/AlmogBaku/ngFacebook/issues/53)
 opened at Jun 4, 2015

> I trying to use ngFacebook on a mobile app but is does not work. I tested on desktop and it works perfect

---

What do you want to achieve? if you need login only , try [official plugin for Facebook in Apache Cordova/PhoneGap](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) - it uses native Facebook plugin. Or [cordova-plugin-facebook4](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4)